# Domain Mapping - Can you use a CNAME instead of an 'a' record

Tags: dns, domain-mapping

So I have a problem - I've previously always done domain mapping by updating the 'a' record with my static IP address. My new hosting provider will not be able to provide me with a static IP address and I am wondering if there is a way to do domain mapping just through CNAMES. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

CNAMEs must always point to another domain name, and not an IP address.
You always need an A record point to an ip addreess and then a CNAME pointing to the A record, or another domain.

Even if they don't give you and ip address they have one for you, so you can reach your domain in some way.

No, it will not affect the SSL on the site. SSL (or TLS) is away from this, DNS resolution occurs first, so when the client knows where to connect the encryption starts and so on.

Comment: Hi Hector. The problem is that their IP address is not static and changes intermittently. I understand that an A record requires an IP, which is why I was hoping there might me a way around it via CNAMEs. It sounds like my best bet will e to switch to a provider that will allow for a static IP address?

Comment: I supose this is about and website, right? Even if their IP changes, you still reach your website in some way, otherwise this will cause serious downtimes. This could be from another CNAME/A records on their side, and in that case you can point your domain CNAMEs to this. AWS do this with load balancers.

Answer (score 0):

Boom - after scouring the internet I found the answer - it's called a 'flattened' CNAME and can be done through CloudFlare. You can see the post here of someone using a WordPress multisite that needed to do this https://markwilkinson.me/2018/10/17/domain-mapping-with-wordpress-multisite-without-using-ip-addresses/#cname-mapping